# Event object is not in the post call response but event object present in the get call response

Tags: java, spring-boot

Refer the below code and response, the post call response doesn't **shows the events in the postcall response**, but it shows the event in the get call response. I am trying to find the cause of the issue.

```java
// sample code for create rem   

     public Rem save(Rem rem) {
                Usr deceased = usrService.findById(rem.getDId());
                rem.setDeceased(deceased);
                rem.setAddress(address));
                List<Event> revents = rem.getEvents();
                rem.setEvents(null);
        
                Rem r = remRepository.save(rem);
    
            List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
            for (Event eve : revents) {
                Event event = Event.create(r, eve.getEventType(), Address.convert(eve.getLocation()), eve.getFromDate(),
                        eve.getToDate());
                events.add(event);
            }
            eveRepository.saveAll(events);
    
            return findById(r.getId());
        }
```

```json
// sample post call rem response
  

     "events": null,
        "medias": null,
        "advertisements": null

// sample get call rem response

    "events": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "location": null,
                    "created_date": "2024-03-01T13:12:06.062+00:00",
                    "modified_date": "2024-03-01T13:12:06.062+00:00",
                    "created_by": null,
                    "modified_by": null,
                    "event_type": "F Service",
                    "address": null,
                    "from_date": "2023-11-30T12:45:29.294+00:00",
                    "to_date": "2023-12-02T12:45:29.294+00:00"
                }
```

Comment: I think you should put the first save of Rem in new Transaction with propagation REQUIRE_NEW, you try to get element by id, but the id is not set yet in the object. 
My apologies for my bad english :)